# Let $G = G_1 * G_2$ free product, where $G_k$ are cyclic and $|G_1| = m$, $|G_2| = n$. If $H = G/[G, G]$, show that $|H| = mn$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = G_1 * G_2$ free product, where $G_k$ are cyclic and $|G_1| = m$, $|G_2| = n$. If $H = G/[G, G]$, show that $|H| = mn$. Anyone can help me pleasea? Thanks to all.

Comment: In fact, abelianization $G^{\rm ab}:=G/[G,G]$ satisfies $(G\ast H)^{\rm ab}\cong G^{\rm ab}\times H^{\rm ab}$. Presumably one could prove this using universal properties, which would be relevant if your course or text uses universal properties to define free products and abelianization.

Comment: There are other form more easy? Sincerily, i don't understand. @anon. Thanks for help!

Comment: I've only seen the definition of $[G, G]$ in my course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $G=G_1\star G_2$ and interpret $G_1,G_2$ as subgroups of $G$.

**Lemma**. If $g_1\in G_1$ and $g_2\in G_2$ then $g_2g_1$ is expressible as $g_1g_2\gamma$ with $\gamma\in[G,G]$.

*Idea*. Notice $g_2g_1=g_1g_2\gamma\iff \gamma=g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}g_2g_1$.

**Proposition**. Every element of $G/[G,G]$ is expressible as $g_1g_2[G,G]$ for a unique choice of elements $g_1\in G_1$ and $g_2\in G_2$.

Try proving the existence and uniqueness parts of this proposition. In fact, you can go further to show that $G/[G,G]\cong G_1\times G_2$.